# How to store a word with # in .cfg file

Tags: python, linux, file

How to store a password containing # in a config file .I have a config file of frmat .cfg and when i try to store password `finally#!` in the variable password the #! gets commented.I am using python to read the file .cfg.I am using ubuntu

My script uses the python configparser

```
from ConfigParser import (
    RawConfigParser,
    NoSectionError,
    NoOptionError,
```

and uses

```
  self.__password = config_parser.get(section, "password")



CONFIG_SECTION = "config"
DEFAULTS = {
    "logger_fmt": "%(asctime)s: %(message)s",
    "logger_file_path": None,
    "persist_memorystate": "false",
}
```

Comment: Though, it depends on what will be *processing* the config file that determines what is and is not a comment. Are you using the `configparser`/`ConfigParser` module?

Comment: @chepner yes i am using ConfigParser

Comment: What does your config file actually look like? And how do you define `config_parser`?

Comment: @chepner
CONFIG_SECTION = "config"
DEFAULTS = {
    "logger_fmt": "%(asctime)s: %(message)s",
    "logger_file_path": None,
    "persist_memorystate": "false",
}

Comment: No, I mean `config_parser = ...` and an example of the configuration file itself.

Comment: @chepner self._cp = config_parser = RawConfigParser(defaults=DEFAULTS)

Comment: @chepner
# Password for the above user



password=finally#!

Comment: # Password for the above user  in one line and rest below it

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `c.get("foo", "password")` returns `'finally#!', not `'finally'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it around with single quot?

Comment: thanks mayaht for your answer